# В каком массиве хранится ответ по AJAX запросу?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть запрос:

```
function getCourierInfo(courierId) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://appserver.com/AppClient_1.0_Boosik/admin/courierchange.php?courier_id=' + courierId,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            success: sendCourierDetails(responseText)
        });
    }
```

Как в `success` функцию передать данные из ответа на мой запрос? В каком массиве он хранится?

Comment: `success: sendCourierDetails` должно быть, а сейчас ты просто вызываешь свою функцию

Comment: Ну я и пытаюсь вызвать свою функцию, в которую параметром хочу передать ответ по этому запросу. Эта функция делает второй `ajax` в контроллер,и ей соответственно нужно отправлять данные, полученные из этого первого запроса.

Comment: я уже сказал как надо сделать. Ну и вообще стоит посмотреть в консоль, наверняка у тебя там ошибка обращения к необъявленой переменной responseText

Comment: _а сейчас ты просто вызываешь свою функцию_ **до того как вызовется первый ajax**

Comment: `success: sendCourierDetails`, `function sendCourierDetails(data) {...}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sendCourierDetails(responseText){
    // в responseText будут данные из ответа на первый запрос
    // Если сервер ответит в формате JSON со всеми нужными заголовками, то тут будет не строка, а ожидаемый массив
    console.log(responseText);
}



function getCourierInfo(courierId) {
        // Первый запрос 
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'http://appserver.com/AppClient_1.0_Boosik/admin/courierchange.php?courier_id=' + courierId,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
            // Назначается обработчик события успешного ответа
            success: sendCourierDetails
        });
    }
```

Comment: в чем отличие от кода в вопросе?

Comment: В параметре назначенного обработчика. Его не надо указывать так.

Comment: почему? добавь пояснение в ответ

Comment: В чём отличие от моего ответа? Кроме того, что я явно исправил одну строку, а тут её ещё и надо в остальном коде найти.

Comment: @Qwertiy Так нагляднее, мне показалось. Автор всё-таки просит не ошибку найти, а показать место, куда приходят данные. В своём ответе я именно это и пытался объяснить.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> success: sendCourierDetails(responseText)
> ```

```
success: sendCourierDetails
```

Comment: где пояснения-то? :-)

Comment: @Grundy, пояснения не планируются :)

Comment: пиши давай! а то плохой ответ

Comment: @Grundy, пиши свой)

Answer (score -6):

Ответ на AJAX запрос хранится в переменной `data`.
Т.е. замените

```
success: sendCourierDetails(responseText)
```

На

```
success: sendCourierDetails(data)
```

Comment: `data` насколько я знаю - это то, что я отправляю в запросе, а не ответ который я получаю.

Comment: `success: sendCourierDetails(responseText)` - абсолютно так же работает как и `success: sendCourierDetails(data)`

Comment: @Klimenkomud после запроса переменная переопределяется

Comment: @Grundy спасибо, буду знать